# Angular -Text Input Field To Accept Only Numbers in Mobile Phones

Tags: html, angular, responsive-design

In angular 9, I created an input field text which only accepts number using this code:

Html File:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>{{fields.label}}</mat-label>
<input
 pattern="[0-9]*"
 [formControlName]="fields.field"
 [id]="fields.field"
 [type]="'text'"
 (keypress)="numericOnly($event)"
 autocomplete="off"
 matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript file:

```
numericOnly(event): boolean {
    return !isNaN(Number(event.key)) && event.key !== ' ';
  }
```

This code is working properly in DESKTOP web browser but my problem is when I access the site in MOBILE PHONE the input field doesn't only accepts numbers but accepts chars.

Please help me to solve this in mobile phones. I still need this to work in safari, chrome and mozilla mobile phone. Thanks guys..

Comment: does this code will help ```inputmode="numeric"``` ?

Comment: since you are using reactive forms use a Validator on that field. also if you change the type to number use only can type numbers and in mobile it will open a number only keypad

Comment: @handsand sorry im using input field text because of some implementation needed for my field. I also have a validators. thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

// It will help you

```
numbersOnly(event) {
        const input = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(input)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm ill let you know if this work. Does this prevent backspace/delete?